# Group by fuzzy string matches with fuzzywuzzy and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataset of random words and names and I am trying to group all of the similar words and names. So given the dataframe below:

```
     Name           ID            Value
0    James           1             10
1    James 2         2             142
2    Bike            3             1
3    Bicycle         4             1197
4    James Marsh     5             12
5    Ants            6             54
6    Job             7             6
7    Michael         8             80007  
8    Arm             9             47 
9    Mike K          10            9
10   Michael k       11            1
```

My pseudo code would be something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

minratio = 95
for idx1, name1 in df['Name'].iteritems():
   for idx2, name2 in df['Name'].iteritems():
      ratio = fuzz.WRatio(name1, name2)
      if ratio > minratio:
          grouped = df.groupby(['Name', 'ID'])['Value']\
                        .agg(Total_Value='sum', Group_Size='count')
```

This would then give me the desired output:

```
print(grouped)
     Name           ID            Total_Value          Group_Size
0    James           1             164                     3 # All James' grouped
2    Bike            3             1198                    2 # Bike's and Bicycles grouped
5    Ants            6             54                      1 
6    Job             7             6                       1
7    Michael         8             80017                   3 # Mike's and Michael's grouped
8    Arm             9             47                      1
```

Obviously this doesn't work, and honestly, I am not sure if this is even possible, but this is what I'm trying to accomplish. Any advice that could get me on the right track would be useful.

Answer (score 10):

Using [affinity propagation clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html) (not perfect but maybe a starting point):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from scipy import spatial
import sklearn.cluster

s="""Name           ID            Value
0    James           1             10
1    James 2         2             142
2    Bike            3             1
3    Bicycle         4             1197
4    James Marsh     5             12
5    Ants            6             54
6    Job             7             6
7    Michael         8             80007  
8    Arm             9             47 
9    Mike K          10            9
10   Michael k       11            1"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),sep='\s\s+',engine='python')

names = df.Name.values
sim = spatial.distance.pdist(names.reshape((-1,1)), lambda x,y: fuzz.WRatio(x,y))
affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", random_state=None)
affprop.fit(spatial.distance.squareform(sim))

res = df.groupby(affprop.labels_).agg(
        Names=('Name',','.join),
        First_ID=('ID','first'),
        Total_Value=('Value','sum'),
        Group_Size=('Value','count')
        )
```

Result

```
                                Names  First_ID  Total_Value  Group_Size
0  James,James 2,James Marsh,Ants,Arm         1          265           5
1                        Bike,Bicycle         3         1198           2
2                                 Job         7            6           1
3            Michael,Mike K,Michael k         8        80017           3
```

Comment: Why does this put `Ants` and `Arm` in the same category as `James`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to take the `WRatio` into account.

Comment: As I said, it's not perfect. Maybe it can be improved by tuning some parameters or applying a different distance measure (where e.g. Ants and James are further apart). Why do you think it doesn't take `WRatio` into account? In fact it is the basis for the clustering. You can print `spatial.distance.squareform(sim)` to see the distance matrix.

Comment: for instance, using Damerau-Levenshtein distance (https://pypi.org/project/pyxDamerauLevenshtein), we get the following groups: `'James,James 2,James Marsh',  'Bike,Bicycle,Mike K',  'Ants,Job,Arm',  'Michael,Michael k'`.