# How to find and group similar terms in a dataframe in order to sum their values?

Tags: python, pandas, tf-idf, difflib

I have data like this:

```
| Term     | Value|
| -------- | -----|
| Apple    | 100  |
| Appel    | 50   |
| Banana   | 200  |
| Banan    | 25   |
| Orange   | 140  |
| Pear     | 75   |
| Lapel    | 10   |
```

Currently, I am using the following code:

```py
matches = []
for term in terms:
    tlist = difflib.get_close_matches(term, terms, cutoff = .80, n=5)
    matches.append(tlist)
      
df["terms"] = matches
```

The output is like this

```
| Term                  | Value|
| --------------------- | -----|
| [Apple, Appel]        | 100  |
| [Appel, Apple, Lapel] | 50   |
| [Banana, Banan]       | 200  |
| [Banan, Banana]       | 25   |
| [Orange]              | 140  |
| [Pear]                | 75   |
| [Lapel, Appel]        | 10   |
```

This code isn't really helpful. My desired output is something like:

```
| Term     | Value|
| -------- | -----|
| Apple    | 150  |
| Banana   | 225  |
| Orange   | 140  |
| Pear     | 75   |
| Lapel    | 10   |
```

The main issue is that the lists aren't in the same order, and often there is only one or two words of overlap in the lists. For example, I might have

- [apple, appel]
- [appel, apple, lapel]

Ideally, I would like to have both these return "apple", because that has the highest value of the overlapping terms.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this helps... [Group by fuzzy string matches with fuzzywuzzy and groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025733/group-by-fuzzy-string-matches-with-fuzzywuzzy-and-groupby)

Comment: This does help, do you know of a way to add a threshold to the WRatio?

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to achieve your goal is to use the Python standard library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module, which provides helpers for computing deltas, like this:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

import pandas as pd

# Toy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Term": ["Apple", "Appel", "Banana", "Banan", "Orange", "Pear", "Lapel"],
        "Value": [100, 50, 200, 25, 140, 75, 10],
    }
)

KEY_TERMS = ("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear")

for i, row in df.copy().iterrows():
    # Get the similarity ratio for a given value in df "Term" column (row[0])
    # and each term from KEY_TERM, and store the pair "term:ratio" in a dict
    similarities = {
        term: SequenceMatcher(None, row[0], term).ratio() for term in KEY_TERMS
    }
    # Find the key term for which the similarity ratio is maximum
    # and use it to replace the original term in the dataframe
    df.loc[i, "Term"] = max(similarities, key=lambda key: similarities[key])

# Group by term and sum values
df = df.groupby("Term").agg("sum").reset_index()
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Outputs
     Term  Value
0   Apple    160
1  Banana    225
2  Orange    140
3    Pear     75
```

Comment: As per the question the last line should probably be `df.groupby('Term').agg('sum').reset_index()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks @MDR. Indeed, I forgot that last part :-) I have updated the answer.